# Setup OAuth2.0 password flow in Swagger UI

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, swagger, springfox

I have a Spring Boot application with Swagger UI. I'd like to implement authentication UI so I can provide username, password, client id, and client secret to login. The returned Bearer token should be used for all calls to the service and be passed though Authorization header.

**THE ISSUE:** client_id and client_secret aren't passed as query params to token url. So token url endpoint returns error because client_id and client_secret are null.

gradle.build

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.2.13.RELEASE'
compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'
```

SwaggerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.controller"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(securitySchema()))
            .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()))
            .apiInfo(metadata());
    }

    private ApiInfo metadata() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("Services API")
            .description("API for working with users")
            .version("1.0")
            .build();
    }

    private OAuth securitySchema() {
        List<AuthorizationScope> authorizationScopeList = new ArrayList();
        List<GrantType> grantTypes = new ArrayList();
        GrantType passwordGrant = new ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant("http://localhost:8080/api/oauth/token");
        grantTypes.add(passwordGrant);

        return new OAuth("oauth2schema", authorizationScopeList, grantTypes);
    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext
            .builder()
            .securityReferences(defaultAuth())
            .forPaths(PathSelectors.ant("/**"))
            .build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        final AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[0];
        return Arrays.asList(new SecurityReference("oauth2schema", authorizationScopes));
    }
}
```

WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthResource {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/token", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity authorize(
        @RequestParam(value = "client_id") String clientId,
        @RequestParam(value = "client_secret") String secret,
        @RequestParam(value = "grant_type") String grantType,
        @RequestParam(value = "username") String username,
        @RequestParam(value = "password") String password) {

    // client id and client secret are null
}
```

**When I put client id/client secret in authorization pop-up and press 'Authorize' swagger doesn't send them to AuthController**
[image]